# Share android screen with other devics

Tags: android, screen, share, vlc, remote-desktop

I am trying to share android screen programatically... basic purpose is to controlling the device remotely like [Optia](https://play.google.com/store/apps/details?id=jp.co.optim.optiasmsng&hl=en) but with multi-touch and long-tap support.

I understand this process has CPU restrictions and may need ROOT.. so its probably done at OS / Linux level. But I can't really find an starting point.

Any ideas how to do it? or where I may learn more

Answer (score 0):

Use **RDP - Remote Desktop Protocol** and use **google** to search that.

Comment: apparently RDP is for connecting to Windows PC... is it?

I want to control an android device with other.

Comment: you mean to say android - to - android?

Comment: @Umair I think you need to have a rooted phone to do that.

Comment: Yes its android to android.. I understand and mentioned in my question that it will be probably done at OS level and I may need root.